# What does it mean "to reshuffle a cabinet"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Does "reshuffle a cabinet" mean reappoint ministers/ heads of the departments to new positions without bringing in new people? Or could it mean, more broadly, to change the heads of ministries/departments, possibly with the introduction of new people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to check this myself, but [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_British_cabinet_reshuffle) shows that a (UK) cabinet reshuffle can include dismissing some members and appointing new ones.

Comment: In Australia (which has a similar political system) a cabinet reshuffle *might* mean moving exactly the same people throughout exactly the same government departments, but it usually means omitting some people, including some others, 'promoting' some to higher-status departments or 'demoting' others. It sometimes includes the amalgamation or separation of some departments (which can also be done at other times). Moving one or two people would not be regarded as a 'reshuffle'. A reshuffle would need many or most.